# HTTPS with Docker Containerised Spring Boot App is not working

Tags: docker, spring-boot, https, spring-cloud

Below are the entries i added to application.properties file to enable HTTPS:

```
server.port: 80
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: password
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

When i start the docker container, url is not accessible with HTTPS. But if i commemt the above lines, http is accessible. This is when app is run as docker image.

If I run spring boot app in my local machine, https is working. Not sure what is wrong or missing.

For information, I'm using the following Docker compose file:

```
ms1:
  image: aa/ms1:localubuntu
  mem_limit: 512
  environment:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker-development-cloud
    JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
  build:
    context: ../../
    dockerfile: ms1/src/main/dockerBuildRelease/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "443:443"
  restart: always
  networks:
    - cloud
```

Comment: Have you tried with `server.port: 443`? You might need to open the port on the container also then. Could you try omitting `classpath:` ?

Comment: Also please post your docker run command

Comment: I am using docker-compose and it works only if use server.port: 443 and   `ms1:
    image: aa/ms1:localubuntu
    mem_limit: 512M
    environment:
     SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker-development-cloud
     JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ms1/src/main/dockerBuildRelease/Dockerfile  
    ports:
    - "443:443"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - cloud `

Comment: But if i try "8000:443" in compose and then do server.port: 8000 it doesnt work.

Comment: @Santosh did you find out what the issue was in the end?

Comment: @Santosh : Did you find solution to your issue. I am also having the same issue where I am trying to have the application on port 8081, and I gave `server.port=8081` and in docker-compose,  `ports:  - "8081:8080"`.

Comment: No, I did not find a solution for this. As a workaround, we used Azure Application Gateway and used SSL offloading.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work on Docker, you need to:

- start your server with a valid port (by valid, I mean either 443, or another not-reserved port, like 8443 for instance). As you already know, this is done by setting the `server.port` property in your `application.yml` file
- expose the server port in your `docker-compose.yml` file. As a remember, the syntax is `host:container`, so assuming you configured your Spring Boot application on port `443`, and want to expose it to the port `8443` on the host, you ports configuration will look like: `8443:443`

Also, it seems strange to me that you're using both `image` and `build` on your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: The image and build is beacuse i use the same docker-compose file for both build and running the application

Comment: As suggested i use 443:8443 to map 443 on the machine to 8443 on the application. This runs on single node, but with docker swarm and application deployed on node 1, i get 404 when i access the app through swarm url, but works fine with node01 IP address. Any suggestions?